# File access in corona project

Tags: path, lua, directory, coronasdk

My project stucture is :

```
assets 
    -- image
        -- my_image.png
scene
    -- start.lua
main.lua
```

from start.lua, I want to show my_image.png with the imagePath is 
"../assets/image/my_image.png", but it's failed. 
Of course, I can do that from the project root. In sub-folder, it's not.
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is not relative to the source file. Try using the same path in `start.lua` than in `main.lua`, i.e. "assets/image/my_image.png".

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have the image in any of your lua files like for instance in "main.lua" you can put:

```
local img = display.newImage("assets/image/my_image.png",x,y)
```

now if you want to put that in your start.lua there is no problem.